# How to autofill a column with sequential number, but based on a parameter?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to add a new column to few MySQL (MariaDB) tables. I want to make the column auto-filled with sequential number. What I figured out so far is:

```
SELECT @count:=0;
UPDATE users SET ordering = @count:=@count+1;
```

It works perfectly. However, I don't know how to make it so that the order in which the numbers are assigned is based on **another value**, namely ascending order of another integer field called `regdate`. Here's an example.

Current result:

| login | regdate | ordering |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user | 1633205589 | 1 |
| guy | 16332060000 | 3 |
| account | 16332090000 | 2 |
| data | 16332095000 | 4 |

What I want:

| login | regdate | ordering |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user | 1633205589 | 1 |
| guy | 16332060000 | 2 |
| account | 16332090000 | 3 |
| data | 16332095000 | 4 |

I hope it's pretty clear and concise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a joined table with ROW_NUMBER

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (
>   `login` VARCHAR(7),
>   `regdate` VARCHAR(20) ,
>   `ordering` INTEGER
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO users
>   (`login`, `regdate`, `ordering`)
> VALUES
>   ('user', '1633205589', '1'),
>   ('guy', '16332060000', '3'),
>   ('account', '16332090000', '2'),
>   ('data', '16332095000', '4');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE users  u1
> JOIN (SELECT `login`, `regdate`, row_number() over (ORDER BY regdate ASC) rn FROM users) u2 
> ON u1.`login` = u2.`login` AND u1.`regdate` = u2.`regdate`
> SET u1.ordering =  u2.rn ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM users
> ```
>
> ```
> login   | regdate     | ordering
> :------ | :---------- | -------:
> user    | 1633205589  |        1
> guy     | 16332060000 |        2
> account | 16332090000 |        3
> data    | 16332095000 |        4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4dc129bef13bcddf39a3fd81b1ae0181)*

Comment: This works as well, results are fully correct, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE users  usr1
JOIN (SELECT @a:=@a+1 rn, id FROM users, (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a) usr2
ON usr1.id = usr2.id 
SET usr.serial =  usr2.rn
```

Comment: Thank you! I already did the thing based on the answers already provided here, but from what I can say, this should work as well, however I can't check it now :)

Comment: Caution:  Setting @variables inside a SELECT is deprecated.  (I don't know when it will eventually be removed.)

Answer (score 1):

Does `users` have a `PRIMARY KEY`?  If so, the following won't work.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;`)

```
CREATE TABLE users2 LIKE users;
ALTER TABLE users2
    ADD COLUMN ordering INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY(ordering);
INSERT INTO users2
    SELECT *,    -- the existing columns
           NULL  -- 1,2,etc automatically filled in
        FROM users;
RENAME TABLE users TO trash,
             users2 TO users;
DROP TABLE trash;
```

What happens when a new user is added?  `AUTO_INCREMENT` automatically gives it the next higher number.  Is that OK?  If you need to renumber the rows, no method is good.

Comment: Hi! It works absolutely okay, as do the other ideas commented by me :D

Answer (score 0):

As long as your update just involves a single table, you can specify an order:

```
UPDATE users SET ordering = @count:=@count+1 ORDER BY regdate;
```

Comment: It works like a charm, wouldn't expect it to be that simple. Thank you!